# Highcharts and JSON problems

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, highcharts

I'm making a timeline graph and I have problem with the data I need the result of the query to the database did not result in double quotes ("). They leave a sample of how I get the result

> [{"name":"Tv Cable","data":["[1370925000000,100]"]},{"name":"Tv Satelital","data":["[1365654600000,100]","[1368505800000,200]","[1370320200000,1500]","[1370925000000,500]","[1370925000000,560]","[1370925000000,50]","[1370925000000,500]","[1370925000000,800]","[1370925000000,500]","[1373776200000,1000]"]},{"name":"Tv Internet","data":["[1371097800000,500]"]},{"name":"Tv Telefonia"}]

I need it follows

> [{"name":"Tv Cable","data":[[1370925000000,100]]},{"name":"Tv Satelital","data":[[1365654600000,100],[1368505800000,200],[1370320200000,1500],[1370925000000,500],[1370925000000,560],[1370925000000,50],[1370925000000,500],[1370925000000,800],[1370925000000,500],[1373776200000,1000]]},{"name":"Tv Internet","data":[[1371097800000,500]]},{"name":"Tv Telefonia"}]

I have while trying to fix it and I have not managed to do?

I let my graphic codes to see what I do

sql.php

```
<?php
$fecha = date("d-m-Y"); // fecha actual 
$ano = date("Y"); // A単o actual 
$mes = date("m"); // Mes actual 
$dia = date("d"); // Dia actual  
$mes_inicio= $mes-2;

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xyolcarx_inter","xYolcar19572059");

if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("xyolcarx_inter", $con);
$rows = array();
for ($i=1;$i<=4;$i++){
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT monto,(unix_timestamp(fecha)*1000) FROM ventas WHERE codigo_ser = '".$i."' ORDER BY fecha ASC ");
$sth2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servicio WHERE codigo_ser= '".$i."'");
while($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($sth2)) {
$rows[$i]['name'] = $r2['servicio'];
}
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
$rows[$i]['data'][] = '['.$r['(unix_timestamp(fecha)*1000)'].','.$r['monto'].']';
}
}
$result = array();
for ($i=1;$i<=4;$i++){  
array_push($result,$rows[$i]);
}
print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

$(function() {

    $.getJSON('sql.php', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart : {
                renderTo : 'container'
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series : data
        });
    });

});

//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
$rows[$i]['data'][] = '['.$r['(unix_timestamp(fecha)*1000)'].','.$r['monto'].']';
```

should look like this

```
$rows[$i]['data'][] = array($r['(unix_timestamp(fecha)*1000)'],$r['monto']);
```

Don't build the json yourself. Just build the array structure, and let json_encode do the rest of the work for you.

---

**edit** more advice:

Change this:

```
SELECT monto,(unix_timestamp(fecha)*1000) FROM ventas...
```

to this:

```
SELECT monto, (unix_timestamp(fecha)*1000) AS fecha_timestamp FROM ventas...
```

so you can access it easier in php:

```
$rows[$i]['data'][] = array($r['fecha_timestamp'],$r['monto']);
```

---

**edit** more advice:

Mysql sometimes has performance issues with `unix_timestamp(fecha)*1000` because it has to turn what it thinks was an 32-bit int into a 64-bit int, and that sucks. Do that in php.

Change this:

```
SELECT monto, (unix_timestamp(fecha)*1000) AS fecha_timestamp FROM ventas...
```

to this:

```
SELECT monto, unix_timestamp(fecha) AS fecha_timestamp FROM ventas...
```

so you can do the work in php:

```
$rows[$i]['data'][] = array($r['fecha_timestamp']*1000,$r['monto']);
```